# Is there a lossy compressed file format for 16-bit dynamic range images?

Tags: jpeg, hdr, black-and-white, file-format, image-compression

I'd like to aggressively compress some scientific 16-bit grayscale image files, but without reducing the dynamic range. Is such a thing possible?

I understand that JPEG format uses lossy, and therefore tunably aggressive, compression, but only supports 8-bits per color channel.

PNG format supports 16-bit grayscale images, but only supports lossless compression, which limits the file compression ratio.

TIFF format also supports 16-bit grayscale images, but as far as I am aware, supports no standard lossy compression of 16-bit images.

Comment: JPEG actually supports 12-bit images!  Not very many people know this, and many programs don't support it.  But, the support is there.

Comment: I think openEXR is what you want. You can be more flexible with color subsampling than jpeg, and tune it better for your scientific data needs.  As I recall, this is developed for/by Pixar.

Comment: [BPG](http://bellard.org/bpg/) supports up tp 14 bits.

Comment: I'm sorry if I'm completely out of line here, but what is wrong with good old ZIP?

Comment: @Ilia Frenkel ZIP is not lossy. (Nor specialized for images)

Comment: Copying an answer from my related question (https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/113747/lossy-archival-compression-for-16-bit-tif-images): HEIC/HEIF seems to be a more standard alternative to BPG. Unfortunately I'm not sure what tools exist to encode 16-bit images though; ImageMagick seems to only output an 8-bit version.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It sounds like what you're looking for is JPEG2000.  It has a range of options including a 16-bit lossy compression and better compression ratios than JPEG.  It hasn't been as widely adopted as hoped (for a host of reasons) and may have some patent issues that might make it difficult to use in certain situations but otherwise it fits your needs.

Personally if I were in your position I'd say storage is cheap and use PNG which is a properly defined and free standard.

Comment: JPEG2000 seems like just the thing. The ImageMagick tools work with jpeg2000; which is support enough for me to proceed with my investigation.

Answer (score 8):

JPEG2000, and you may also want to look at OpenEXR because it is supported by video hardware.

Answer (score 3):

The maximum dynamic range of a *linear* 8-bit encoding is only 8 stops, however the dynamic range you can store with a *nonlinear* encoding is limitless.

Thus I would suggest you apply a strong tonecurve to the images and then you can use standard JPEG without losing dynamic range. When you want to use the original images, convert them to 16-bit and apply the inverse tonecurve.

That is of course if dynamic range is your only concern. If you also need to preserve *tonal range* then you might have to roll your own lossy compression...

Comment: Similarly, you could pre-process the images in ways that discard the information that you know you don't care about, prior to saving as losslessly compressed 16-bit PNG or TIFF.

Comment: This is what video camera are doing with log picture profile but from experience I can say it’s a very bad bad idea because the reduction in information is fixed instead of using variable lossiness. Using openEXR lossy compression would give much better result.